# How to send the size of element back to Controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app where there a container div that will contain a bunch of elements I have to dynamically size based on the available space in the container div.

The container div will be styled and sized through CSS. However, and this is the issue... The container div will be specified with % (i.e., width: 90%;), so I don't know the pixel sizes of it.

I need the size of that div (width and height) in order to do the calculations in the controller. How do I get at that div's width and height and pass it to the controller?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use offsetHeight and offsetWidth.

```
var height = angular.element('#nameofelement').offsetHeight;

var width = angular.element('#nameofelement').offsetWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you?

```
var container_width = $(".container_class").width()

var container_height = $(".container_class").height()
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gtqr3hx1/3/